# Haskell: functions and values

Tags: haskell

I am a beginner in Haskell and have a problem with the def of functions in Haskell.
Values are functions in Haskell, right?
(+3) 3 = 6 but what does (+3) (+3) mean.
Does (+3)  counts as  an value  ?

Comment: What? Read [some material](http://learnyouahaskell.com/chapters) first.

Comment: `(+3) (+3)` won't work, unless you've made `a -> a` a `Num` instance. That being said, if you're interested in definitions, you should have a look at the Haskell report.

Comment: const x y =  x
negate x  = -x  we should calc const const(negate1)(negate2)3    At the first step my Tutor calculate                const const(negate1) to const but

Comment: @EugeneSh. Have you ever wondered what was your mindstate before learning something? Perhaps when you are writing teaching material. I have and this questions allow me to see a little bit of myself in the past. And it is a valid question anyway, so why not let the search engines decide how relevant/good question it is.

Comment: @LayGonzález The **right** mind state before learning something should be the curiosity. I guess we have it here. But then comes the learning skill, that can be learned by itself. The very first learning skill should be: *first things first*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`(+3) (+3)` is simply a type error and, therefore, it won't compile.

The type of `(+3)` is `Int -> Int`, which means that when applying an `Int`, we get another `Int`. It also means that **you can only apply values of type `Int`!**

So, you can't apply to `(+3)` a value of type `Int -> Int`, only values of type `Int`.

So yes, `(+3)` is value, but not of the right type to apply it to a function that expects a value of type `Int`.

`Int` can't be unified with `Int -> Int` because they have different **type constructor**, which makes them different types, as pointed out by @DanielWagner. The outermost constructor of `Int -> Int` is `->` while the outermost constructor of `Int` is simply `Int`. It is sufficient that two types have different outermost constructor for considering them different.

Comment: thats make sense. but why does  compose = foldr (.) id      work                  foldr::(a -> b -> b) -> b -> [a] -> b   but id type is b->b

Comment: The type of `(.)` is `(b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c`, which is the same as `(b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> (a -> c)`. It makes sense, function compositions, takes 2 functions and returns a function.
The type of foldr is `(a -> b -> c) -> b -> [a] -> b`.
To remove ambiguity, lets rename the type variables to this:
`foldr :: (fa -> fb -> fb) -> fb -> [fa] -> fb`.
`(.) :: (cb -> cc) -> (ca -> cb) -> (ca -> cc)`.
Then, it's clear that the application `foldr (.)` has this type:
`(ca -> cb) -> [cb -> cb] -> (ca -> cb)`.
Also:
`(.) :: x -> x`.
and finally, `foldr (.) id`is:
`[x -> x] -> (x -> x)`.

Comment: The key idea that you seem to be missing is that types of this kind: `(cb -> cc)` can be unified with type variables like `fa`; what I did was to exactly replace all `fa`s with `(cb -> cc)`. And something similar for `fb`&`(ca->cb)`.

Comment: And also, if you have types like `a`=`(x -> y)` and `b`=`(x -> z)` and you unify `a` with `b` then, that unification will force `y`=`z`. That is why we ended with only 1 type variable, `x`; because the unifications that where done forced to all type variables to belong to the same type.

Comment: Since `(ca -> cb)` got unified with `(ca -> cc)` that means that `cb = cc` and therefore I actually replaced `fa` with `(cb -> cb)` instead of `(cb ->cc)`, but it is the same.
`(ca -> cb)` got unified with `(ca -> cc)` because `foldrs` type says that the resulting type of `foldr` is the same as the type of its second parameter: `(fa -> fb -> fb) -> fb -> [fa] -> fb`, see how `fb` appears as the type for the second parameter and the resulting value?

Comment: So, you can say that `(a -> b)` = `c` since the three are all **type variables**, but you can't say that `(Int -> Int)` = `Int`, because Int is a **type** not a type variable and the **kind** of `(Int -> Int) :: (* -> *)` doesn't match the kind of `Int :: (*)`. `(* -> *)` != `*`

Comment: Thank you very much! so simply a parameter like a can stand for (b->c)       and that was the main point  i didnt get. Thank you for your  detailed answer

Comment: Yes, `a` could be unified with `b -> c`. The unification algorithm is very clever and if you say `a` = `b -> c` & `a` = `b -> d`, then the algorithm will unify `c` with `d`. And if for some reason `c` != `d` (maybe you previously unified `c` with `Int` and `d` with `(Int -> Int)` then the unification would fail and you would get a compile error.

Comment: @LayGonzález `Int -> Int` does not have kind `* -> *`; it has kind `*`, just like `Int`. But the outer-most (type) constructor of `Int -> Int` is `(->)`, while the outer-most constructor of `Int` is `Int`, and only type with the same outer-most constructor may unify.

Comment: @DanielWagner Oh that is correct. Thanks for pointing it out. I will edit my response and give you some credit.

Answer (score 3):

`(+3)` isn't what you probably think it is. In other languages, this means the numerical value *positive‑three*. In Haskell it's the partial application of the `+` operator, and is a function taking one argument (the other number to add). It adds three to whatever it's given. So `(+3) x` is the application of the function `(+3)` to the value `x` and returns `x+3`. However, `(+3)` `(+3)` tries to add `3` to the *function* `(+3)` which doesn't make sense and gives a type error.

It might help to imagine replacing `+` with a regular function called `plus`:

```
plus x y = y + x
```

Then, `(+3)` is equivalent to `plus 3`, and `(+3) 3` to `(plus 3) 3` which is the same as `plus 3 3`. However, `(+3) (+3)` is equivalent to `(plus 3) (plus 3)` or `plus 3 (plus 3)` which doesn't make sense.

You might want to think about what `(+3) . (+3)` means. This chains together two applications of adding three, and is a single-argument function that adds six.